# Session start request using UDP sockets

Tags: linux, session, udp, handshake

I have been using UDP sockets to send and receive voice through RTP packetization. It is pretty straightforward. I just send my mic voice signals ( that are encoded ) over IP using User Datagram socket , and on the other end i receive the UDP-RTP packets and decode them to be able to play them on my speakers.

I have been searching on internet for a while to find a way to start up a session using UDP sockets. What i want to to is to a Handshake-like process between two ends of my conversation and after the requests were acknowledged the media layer ( which i described in first paragraph ) would fire and start sending voice.

I have not been able to find any tutorials on session request using UDP sockets but i suppose it shouldnt be impossible.( one user sends a request to build a session and if the other user confirms media layer starts)

Has anyone done something like this before? any info is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, UDP is a connectionless, unreliable protocol, you won't find anything like handshaking for negotiating connection i.e no session management. But, to transport RTP packets it's not a good idea to use tcp, it lacks realtime feature, so you have to stick with UDP. Now, to overcome the signaling problem you can use protocols like. SIP. It's standard signaling protocol used in VOIP. SIP initiates a connection before sending RTP packets. To properly use SIP and RTP you might have to take help of another protocol called SDP, which tells which port to use for transmitting RTP and other various info. You can get more info about these techniques [here](http://www.voip-info.org/). Hope this will helps!